# Calling Stat on multiple files - Linux

Tags: linux

So I need to call stat on numerous flies and output the result to a text file. I've tried this

```
stat 'Dir/$file_names' -c %n,%s,%y >> meta.txt
```

$file_name is in the format:

```
"file1" "file2" "file3"
```

But it doesn't work as the quotes are remaining in the path when stat is called.

Is there a way to remove them or to maybe loop through the string?

Also some of the file names have spaces so I quotes will probably needed to specify the file

The file name string is set with the following command

```
file_name=`ssh user@server  find /attachments -type f -mtime -100 -daystart -printf '\"%f\"\ ' `
```

Comment: Your question is more a shell scripting question than related to `stat`. So read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "`$file_names` is in the format `"file1" "file2" "file3"`" ?   How *precisely* is the `file_names` shell variable set ?

Comment: It's a string set using a find command

Comment: Basically I have a find command and I want to call stat on the results of the find and store this in a text file

Comment: Show the entire script, with the `find` command, in your question...

Comment: I have edited the question with the full script that set the $file_name string

Comment: So what I did was write the file into a text file and then loop through each line `while read line; do
    stat Dir/"$line" -c %n,%s,%y >> meta.txt
done < tmp.txt`

Answer (score 1):

In order for variables to be expanded, use double quotes:

```
stat "Dir/$file_names" -c %n,%s,%y >> meta.txt
```

If `$file_names` contains multiple file names, then you can use a for loop and format the variable in a way that uses delimiters. For example, you can use `:` to separate file names, so instead of:

```
"file1" "file2" "file3"
```

use this instead:

```
file1:file2:file3
```

And then set the `IFS` special variable (it's called "Internal Field Separator" and is recognized by the shell) to `:` and use a for loop:

```
IFS=":"
for f in $file_names
do
    stat "Dir/$f" -c %n,%s,%y >> meta.txt
done
```

This can also be a one-liner if you just need a single command:

```
IFS=":"; for f in $file_names; do stat "Dir/$f" -c %n,%s,%y >> meta.txt; done
```

This will ensure that everything works correctly even if your file names contain spaces, like:

```
file1:file with spaces:even   more   spaces
```

Comment: Probably won't work, since the shell would expand the first argument to `Dir/file1 file2 file3` but the OP wants `Dir/file1 Dir/file2 Dir/file3` ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch My mistake. I thought it only contains one file name. A for loop solves that though.

Comment: If file_names contained `a,b,c` then you could get it working with `eval stat Dir/{${file_names}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this and it worked this way:

```
list_of_file="Dir/file1 Dir/file2 Dir/file3"
stat $list_of_file -c %n,%s,%y >> meta.txt
```

The meta.txt will contain stat output from all file.

Answer (score 0):

Try perhaps

```
 for f in $file_names ; do
    stat Dir/$f -c %n,%s,%y >> meta.txt
 done
```

But this might not do what you want if you want to deal with filenames with spaces (which I try hard to avoid).

Read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is `find`.

For all files within a directory

`"%a %n"` will show the permis:

```
find . -exec stat -c "%a %n" '{}' \;
```

for a specific file, like in your scenario:

```
find /Dir/file* -exec stat -c "%a %n" '{}' \;
```